# HttpClient redirecting where use Identityserver4 token provider

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, identityserver4

I have a mvc .net core client that use identityserver4 server token for call a web api. The end user login by login page on identityserver4 and redirect to mvc client,then end user can call protected resources by .net core Httpclient class from web api that is secured too.where user have grant and required claims all things is ok.but where user hasn't specific claim protected api return a 403 status code.

```
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            ....Redirect To Identityserver4 login page....
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

my question is how i can redirect to login page in Identityserver4 where get a 403 error forbidden?

Comment: You would need to perform a new request with the URL of the login page.  There may be an invalid cookie that is going to a different URL that is giving the failure.  when there is no cookie the server is automatically going to the login.

Comment: Seems you are talking about a 403 from the web api. The web api doesn't redirect the user to IdentityServer. It simply validates the access token and can respond with 403. The client can handle the response from the web api in various ways, e.g. send to an access denied page or show an error message. Why do you want to redirect the user to the login page? The user is already logged in. And why should it make a difference? Why would the claim be available now? If this is some sort of caching problem, try using access tokens with shorter lifetime.